# SharePoint 2010 Architecture

Tags: architecture

I am looking for a good book which explains me the architecture of SharePoint 2010. 
Can somebody please let me know the details of the book or any material.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

I just started out with SharePoint in May and I read through the 'Microsoft SharePoint 2010 Unleashed' book ([http://www.amazon.com/Microsoft-SharePoint-2010-Unleashed-Michael/dp/0672333252](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672333252)) and 'Real World SharePoint 2010' ([http://www.amazon.com/Real-World-SharePoint-2010-Indispensable/dp/0470597135](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0470597135)) although I went through the first one a lot more thoroughly. I'm not sure if these are specific to the SharePoint architecture but they do go into a lot of the different SharePoint components and features.

Also try these links I have bookmarked for reference: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552610.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263199.aspx (I didn't really find what I needed here buy you might find it useful)

Hopefully those are a good starting point, thats just where I started.

Answer (score 0):

If you search the web theres a few documents floating around linked in which are brilliant. I know many don't like linked in but it's a nice resource for documents and professional views.

Answer (score 0):

Yup there are a few resources:

**SharePoint 2010 Architecture**

http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Falanandrewdias.files.wordpress.com%2F2011%2F08%2Fsharepoint-2010-architecture.pptx&ei=YjJTUO3gJejZ0QWXtYDADw&usg=AFQjCNHA0iZeldnyerhAQL4RRfl2Db1Xmw&sig2=zYdSjsXiR3NVRDBz3bmIFg

I also recommend this book:

**Practical SharePoint 2010 Information Architecture**

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Practical-SharePoint-2010-Information-Architecture/dp/1430241764/ref=pd_sim_b_2

also

**SharePoint 2010 Enterprise Architect's Guidebook**

http://www.amazon.co.uk/SharePoint-2010-Enterprise-Architects-Guidebook/dp/0470643196

The next best place that I use daily is msdn! It has a vast ammount of info on all products todo with .net.... for sharepoint its well documented.

**SharePoint 2010 Architectures Overview**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg552610.aspx

this is whitepaper:

http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/sharepoint-2010/archive/2010/11/15/sharepoint-2010-user-management.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to almostSharePointMaster for including my book on the list, but "Practical SharePoint Information Architecture" is not an 'Architecture' book that pertains to the question in the initial post. It is much more focused on the combination of BA/IA skills and tools needed for spec'ing a successful SharePoint project.

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Practical-SharePoint-2010-Information-Architecture/dp/1430241764/ref=pd_sim_b_2